# Does the compact-open topology make Top a (symmetric) closed category?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Does the category Top of topological spaces, equipped with the compact-open topology on hom-sets,
form a [closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category#definition)?

(Perhaps even a symmetric closed category? This notion is mentioned in the above linked nLab page and defined in [this article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-embedding-closed-categories/2C8056962667C05B62A3492BCCFB4A2B).)

Note: it is known that Top cannot form a Cartesian closed category, even when restricted to the exponentiable spaces;
cf. [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convenient+category+of+topological+spaces#counterexamples).

---

Edit: In trying to verify the axioms "directly",
I am getting stuck trying to show the function
$$
L^X_{Y,Z} : [Y,Z] \xrightarrow{f \mapsto f_*} [[X,Y],[X,Z]]
$$
is continuous (or show it need not be). Would anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this step?

Comment: You should show your work.  What unit object do you propose?  What are the steps that need to be proved?  What were your attempts to prove them?

Comment: I think the one-point space would be the appropriate unit object. However, I'm still working through the steps.

Comment: Include your work in the question.  Otherwise it is likely to be closed.

Comment: @GEdgar since closed categories are quite non-standard to consider (based on my limited experience, I guess they might be quite relevant in categorical logic) I don’t think this is some kind of exercise. In particular I don’t really see what effort OP could have made (if it is true it means dissecting the topologies on $[X,Y],Z$ and stuff, which sounds tedious, and if it is false it is not immediate (to me) why). In fact I find this a very interesting question.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's known that $\mathsf{Top}$ admits a unique (up to isomorphism) symmetric closed monoidal structure (see, for instance, Činčura's _Closed Structures on Categories of Topological Spaces_. Moreover, in this structure the internal hom is given the topology of pointwise convergence. So if you want a closed structure on $\mathsf{Top}$ whose internal hom is the compact-open topology, it cannot come from a (symmetric) monoidal closed structure.

Comment: Uniqueness of the symmetric monoidal structure is shown in Činčura's earlier paper "Tensor products in the category of topological spaces". By tensor products he means monoidal structures that extend to closed structures. Also, unless I'm misremermbering, a closed structure would require that evaluation at points is continuous, hence that the internal hom topology is at least as fine as the pointwise convergence topology.